# How to write some conditional code more efficiently?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, conditional-statements

What could be a better way of coding the following? There's some conditional code that checks the int value of reviewStarsNumber  and then displays the appropriate uiimage based on the result. It seems long at the moment and I'm imagining that it could be simplified.

thanks for any help

```
  if ([reviewsStarsNumber intValue] == 0) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-0.png"];        
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
}

if ([reviewsStarsNumber intValue] == 10) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-0_5.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
}

if ([reviewsStarsNumber intValue] == 20) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-1_0.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
}

if ([reviewsStarsNumber intValue] == 30) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-1_5.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
}

if ([reviewsStarsNumber intValue] == 40) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-2_0.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
}

if ([reviewsStarsNumber intValue] == 50) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-2_5.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
}

if ([reviewsStarsNumber intValue] == 60) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-3_0.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
}

if ([reviewsStarsNumber intValue] == 70) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-3_5.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
}

if ([reviewsStarsNumber intValue] == 80) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-4_0.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
}

if ([reviewsStarsNumber intValue] == 90) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-4_5.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
}
if ([reviewsStarsNumber intValue] == 100) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-5_0.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
}
```

Comment: Lots of good answers below, but note that at a minimum you should have been using else if statements to avoid evaluating your property in every conditional block.

Comment: While the recommendations below are good to solve this problem generically, the real problem here is that you are using an individual image for each rating. Instead, you could have just an image of a full star, a half star, and possibly an empty star, and then lay them out in a line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you rename the images you could do this:

```
NSUInteger number = [reviewsStarsNumber intValue]
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hstarts-%d.png", number];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
[self.reviewStars setImage:img];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 UImage imageNamed;
 switch([reviewsStarsNumber intValue])
 {
    case 0; imageNamed = hstars0; break;
    case 10: imageNamed = hstars0-5; break;
    // 20,30...
    case 100: imageNamed = hstars5; break;

    default: break;
 }
 [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
```

Comment: it's pretty much teh same thing but much easier on first look.

Answer (score 2):

1.Create plist file, call it 'hstars' for example. Put inside entries with key = 0, 10, 20... and values = hstars-0_5.png, hstars-1_5.png hstars-2_5.png

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hstars" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

2.Or

`NSDictionary *dict = @{@10:@"hstars-0_5.png", @20:@"hstars-1_5.png", ....}`

then just

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:reviewsStarsNumber ]]];
[self.reviewStars setImage:img];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways, but I would say best option would be a switch statement.

```
switch([reviewsStarsNumber intValue])
{
 case 0:
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-0.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
    break;
 case 10:
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-0_5.png"];
    [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
    break;
.
.
.
.
(etc..)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a switch statement:

```
UIImage *img = NULL;
int number = [reviewsStarsNumber intValue];
switch (number)
{
    case 0:
        img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-0.png"];
        break;

    case 10:
        img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hstars-0_5.png"];
        break;

    // ...

    default:
        // ...
        break;
}
[self.reviewStars setImage:img];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a switch statement.

```
switch (expression)
{
   case match1:
        statements
        break;
    case match2:
        statements
        break;
    default:
        statements
        break;
}
```

Or, you could rename your image files to `hstars-<0 - 100>.png` and load them with:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hstars-%@.png", reviewsStarsNumber]];
[self.reviewStars setImage:img];
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a table and look up the rating in that table:

```
static struct
{
    int rating;
    NSString *image;
} ratings[] =
{
   { 0, @"hstars-0.png" },
   ...
   { 100, @"hstars-5_0.png" }
};

const unsigned numRatings = sizeof(ratings) / sizeof(ratings[0]);
int rating = [reviewsStarsNumber intValue];
BOOL found = NO;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < numRatings && !found; i++)
{
    if (ratings[i].rating == rating)
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:ratings[i].image];
        [self.reviewStars setImage:img];
        found = YES;
    }
}

if (!found)
{
    // Perhaps do something if the rating wasn't found?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the first image to `hstars-0-0.png`, then this code should give you what you want.

```
int value = [reviewsStarsNumber intValue] / 10

int highIndex = value / 2
int loxIndex = value % 2 == 1 ? 5 : 0

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hstars-%d_%d.png", highIndex, lowIndex]];
```